# try list of all ip in a query string javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

Hi i have an url like this:http://172.16.254.254/index.php?url=http://172.16.1.3%2f

Hi need to pass in url value all thr ip v4 address in javascript.

Any suggestion?

I did that in php but i want try to do in javascript.

```
for (var key in p) {
   if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
   console.log(key + " -> " + p[key]);
 }
}
```

Comment: What does "all thr ip v4 address" mean?

Comment: from 0.0.0.0 to  255.255.255.255

Comment: If you want to do all IPs, what does that have to do with the IP in the query string?

Comment: Oh, you mean you want to do something with `url=http://0.0.0.0`, then `url=http://0.0.0.1`, and so on?

Comment: i want to chenge de url parameters in query string with all te value from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 in javascript

Comment: yes barmar " 
Oh, you mean you want to do something with url=http://0.0.0.0, then url=http://0.0.0.1, and so on"

Comment: You know how many different IPs that is? 4294967296

Comment: And most of them are not valid URLs. Everything above 224.0.0.0 is multicast addresses.

Comment: yes but i have all the combination in an array (already generated)

Comment: Then what's the problem? Just concatenate it to the URL.

Comment: yes but how in javascript?

Comment: Use `+` to concatenate strings.

Comment: some example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through your array of IPs and concatenate to the URL

```
ipArray.forEach(ip => {
    var url = 'http://172.16.254.254/index.php?url=http://' + ip;
    // do whatever you want with url
});
```